# Windows 7: AMD: Need to adjust the desktop offset and size within the same screen resolution on TV monitor

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, hdmi, resolution, amd-radeon

My father is using a Panasonic TC-32C12 Widescreen TV for a monitor on a Windows 7 Pro 64 system with an AMD Radeon RX550 video card via HDMI. The TV manual explicitly states use with a PC is not the expected use. The TV frame cuts off the visible edges of the display. My father will not switch to an actual PC monitor.

This is now my problem because I'm the computer guy in the family. I need to tell Windows or AMD to change the usable screen size within the set resolution.

**Changing the resolution does not fix this issue.**

I know it can be done, and I have done it before, but I can't remember how.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for 'underscan/overscan' settings.

[Lifewire](https://www.lifewire.com/fix-overscan-in-windows-10-5179410) says for an AMD -

> you can use the Radeon Software app to fix overscan issues by opening it, clicking Settings > Display, and adjusting the HDMI Scaling slider.

See also - [AMD - Resize an Image to Fit the Screen of an HDMI™ Display](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/dh3-022)